# Get specific part of document

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying Mongo db and I wonder if it's possible to only get a specific part of a document?

For example I have:

```
{
  "name" : "MongoDB",
  "info" : { x : 203, y : 102 }
}
```

and I only want the content of `info`.

The closest I found is `db.collection.find({}, { info: 1 })`  but this returns me `{ "info" : { x : 203, y : 102 } }` when I only need `{ x : 203, y : 102 }`.

Comment: I am also interested in the solution as my documents are +5mb in size and I am after specific fields only. No, I can't save the specific fields in a separate table as I store multiple fields in one document (+10k fields)

Answer (score 29):

You could do

```
db.collection.find({},{'info.x':1, 'info.y':1})
```

but that means listing each and every item of the info object in the projection - which may or may not be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `distinct()` function that resembles by following:

```
db.collection.distinct("info", {info : {$exists : true}})
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why this was at 0?  It sounds like the exactly correct answer while the top 2 imply that what the poster wants to do is impossible.

Comment: Even though it has "distinct" keyword, it's not selecting distinct items as mysql does, it selects only that "distinct" field that you provide. So this answer produces actually much better results then other 2 answers.

Answer (score 11):

No, you cannot return just the values for x/y; even if you limit the fields the outer structure is still returned.

See [Result Projections](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

- Starting `Mongo 4.2`, the [`$replaceWith`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/#pipe._S_replaceWith) aggregation operator can be used to replace a document by another (in our case by a sub-document):

  ```
  // { name: "MongoDB", info: { x: 203, y: 102 } }
  db.collection.aggregate({ $replaceWith: "$info" })
  // { "x" : 203, "y" : 102 }
  ```
- Prior to `Mongo 4.2` and starting `Mongo 3.4`, [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/#pipe._S_replaceRoot) can be used in place of `$replaceWith`:

  ```
  db.collection.aggregate({ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$info" } })
  ```

Answer (score 0):

[MongoDb docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

read this

in this,If you specify no projection, the find() method returns all fields of all documents that match the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/aggregation-introduction/):

1. $match phase (optional) to filter result.
2. $project phase to select fields

   `db.getCollection('yourCollection').aggregate([
       {$match:{_id:ObjectId("566fc97f5b79dff1a73ca2ae")}},
       {$project:{_id:0, "x":"$info.x", "y":"$info.y"}}
   ])`