# Spring Data For MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-mongo

I am using `mongodb with spring mvc` for a REST API. I have a controller which adds comments for events. This controller use a method of my event service. And implementation of them are below. However It seems to me as if my mongodb connection works without `transaction`. I have `1 insert` and `1 update` in that my controller adding comment. If update of event throws an error, the request commits inserting.Why is it not doing rollback? How can I fix this problem?

```
public Comments addComment(Comments comment) throws Exception{
    comment.setCommentDate(SowUtil.getDateTimeDB());
    comment.setCommenter(personService.findPersonById("531cc90e3c37b20bef47dfc7"));
    mongoTemplate.insert(comment);
    Events adv = findEventById(comment.getEventId());
    adv.addComment(comment);
    eventService.save(adv);
    return comment;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB does not have the same notion of transactions as RDBMS. Based on your example, it looks like you are using two documents.

MongoDB has an article on 2-phase commit patterns involving multiple documents (
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/). Perhaps, that can help you implementing a rollback?

I believe that Spring also has a notion of transaction support for MongoDB (http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mongodb.html).

Comment: Honestly I am suprised. It should keep transaction for all commits between a request and reponse cycle. The first link you gave is kind of workaround and it is slowing down my system. I think there must be a solution. I keep searching

Comment: Or maybe you can advice for better data representation for that my model described above. As you can see from my question there is OnetoMany relation between Events and comments. and that is why I thought I should have 2 document. do you advice I should have 1 document instead

Comment: Before changing the data model, is there a particular reason why you do not want to use RDBMS? Also, have you looked at the Spring's transaction synchronization feature?

Comment: Yes I have a reason, up to now, mongodb completely covers my requirements. I am trying to make a social app which exactly depends on geographical data. And mongodb does this very well and faster then Relational Database. I have many geo queries.

Comment: As I search and read from internet, It is difficult to do what I need here. And I decided to put all comments in events document so that I can handle it in 1 query and 1 document. Howeever, I would like to ask you it is possible to decide retrieve event with all comments and without comments in spring

Comment: You could try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301795/mongodb-get-specific-part-of-document