# What is the best way to return the subdocument from mongo db (Spring data)

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

For a collection called "test":

`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5848604af8ea274676b6asd8"),
    "test2" : 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "name" : "test3"
        }
}`

is there a way to directly have mongo return the sub-document of type "test2" rather than the parent document? (using spring-data-mongo)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongodb get specific part of document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301795/mongodb-get-specific-part-of-document)

Comment: There are many ways to find it. You can use aggregation framework or projection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can find same by using the **distinct** projection.
If your collection name is test then-

Kindly Run-

```
db.test.distinct("test2")
```

Comment: Little late to acknowledge but thanks for the answer, it did what I wanted.

Comment: @Rakesh Could you please mark it as correct answer. It will helps other as well. Thanks in advance