# How to query a complex MongoDB document from python?

Tags: python, mongodb

I am new to backend development. The project I am working on requires me to query a complex document in Python.
My document looks like this:

```
{
        "_id": "1",
        "results": {
            "steps": 
            [
                {
                    "configuration": {
                        "Api": "/home/data",
                        "Method": "GET",
                     
                    },
                    "result": [
                        {
                            "callTime": "2021-04-15 1:06:05",
                            "responseTime": 0.021202428732067347
                        },
                        {
                            "callTime": "2021-04-15 4:06:05",
                            "responseTime": 0.010961456689983606
                        },
                        {
                            "callTime": "2021-04-15 6:06:35",
                            "responseTime": 0.02298594592139125
                        },
                        {
                            "callTime": "2021-04-15 8:06:35",
                            "responseTime": 0.009161950089037418
                        }
                    ],
                    
                }
            ],
            "success": 4,
            "total": 4
        },
        "schedule": {
            "count": 2,
            "description": "To be run in every 30 seconds",
            "id": "60780fef106737001487bd2e",
            "name": "Test1",
            "periodSeconds": 30
        },
        
    }
```

What I want is that if I give a datetime input then I am supposed to get the **entire** document but with only those results the "callTime" of which are after the input datetime.
Please let me know if anymore additional information is required. Thanks.

Here's a code I have been implementing as of now from python:

```
async def get_results(request, security_context):
    query_filter = {}
    result_time_greater_than = request['minimumTime']
    results = await result_object.get_data(query_filter=query_filter, security_context=security_context)
    document = []
    for result in results:
        a = {}
        for key in set(result.keys()):
            if key != 'results':
                a[key] = result[key]
            else:
                a['results']['success'] = result['results']['success']
                a['results']['total'] = result['results']['total']
                innerResult = result['results']['steps']
                a['results']['steps'] = []
                for innerDict in innerResult:
                    x = {}
                    for j in set(innerDict.keys()):
                        if j != 'result':
                            x[j] = innerDict[j]
                        else:
                            x['result'] = []
                            for innermost in innerDict['result']:
                                if innermost['callTime'] > result_time_greater_than:
                                    x['result'].append(innermost)
                    a['results']['steps'].append(x)
        document.append(a)
    return web.Response(text=json.dumps(document, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str), status=200)
```

If someone can help me first of all shorten the code by adding the right query filter, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem?

Comment: Hello sir, first of all thanks a lot for your response. I haven't been able to come up with any code as of now. I am looking for some help in how to query it. That's all.

Comment: Hello, have added a short code which is close to my implementation. We are using mongo DAO in retrieving data. Let me know if this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what we found out. In MongoDB, there's no way to get a **partial document** from a collection as an output. We can only get complete documents.

Here's a small experiment that we found in the official documentation of MongoDB:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/

Here's the JSON data that we have in our document from the example taken in the documentation:

```
[
{ item: "journal", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 15 } ] },
{ item: "notebook", instock: [ { warehouse: "C", qty: 5 } ] },
{ item: "paper", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 60 }, { warehouse: "B", qty: 15 } ] },
{ item: "planner", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 40 }, { warehouse: "B", qty: 5 } ] },
{ item: "postcard", instock: [ { warehouse: "B", qty: 15 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 35 } ] }
]
```

Here let's say we want to get only those warehouses where the quantity of a specific item is greater than 30. For that we write the following query:

```
db.inventory.find( { 'instock.qty': { $gte: 30 } } )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("607843458fad635d5eaa2ebf"), "item" : "paper", "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : 60 }, { "warehouse" : "B", "qty" : 15 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("607843458fad635d5eaa2ec0"), "item" : "planner", "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "A", "qty" : 40 }, { "warehouse" : "B", "qty" : 5 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("607843458fad635d5eaa2ec1"), "item" : "postcard", "instock" : [ { "warehouse" : "B", "qty" : 15 }, { "warehouse" : "C", "qty" : 35 } ] }
```

As we can see, it's similar to the question we had (getting information of those objects that are having `callTime` less than an input time).

Although we are looking for information of warehouses that is having quantity of an item greater than 30, instead of just getting that warehouse, we are getting complete documents where there is at least one warehouse with `qty` greater than 30.
So parsing through the output is the only way to get just a part of the document that satisfies our requirement.

We found an old question. Hope it helps:
[Get specific part of document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301795/get-specific-part-of-document/5301835)

If someone finds something else, please let us know. Thanks.

I would like to add that the example data and query that we have presented here is from the official documentation the link of which is given.

Thanks.